# How do i access array from json array using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, local-storage

i am trying to access the array from  json Array.
Following is my Json Array :-

```
[
    {
        "arr_id":1,
        "arr_name":"Abc",
        "arr_gender":"Female",
        "arr_location":"PQR",
        "arr_skills":[
            {
                "skills":"PHP",
                "level":"Intermediate"
            },
            {
                "skills":"Angular JS",
                "level":"Beginner"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am Using localStorage dependency  to save Json data.

Query:- 
how do I get particular `skills`(object) from nested json data?

Comment: Would `localstorage.someArray[0].arr_skills` work?

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: Please give some more information, what is the name in which the array is stored in localstorage? If  your json if the format you specified, then `JSON.parse(localstorage.<arrray_name>)[0].arr_skills` **MUST work**.

Comment: it is not working either..

Comment: array name is candidateArr

Comment: Do you want the list of skills or a single skill? `arr_skills` will return you an array, use `arr_skills[0].skills` to access the values or so...

Comment: I got it from "nabin's" answer below..Thanks for the help !

Comment: i want to update the PHP to some other skill from dropdown... i am trying to do this: array[0].skills = $scope.skills; which is not working.  where array[0].skills is my PHP value i am getting that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

```
var a =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('your_name_used_to_save_in_localstorage'));
```

and

```
a[0].arr_skills
```

Comment: This is returning object...how do i access my skills and level from that object?

Comment: use loop for a[0].arr_skills and for each loop you will get individual object and hence level.

Comment: var a =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("candidateArray"));
  console.log(a[0].arr_skills);
  var array = a[0].arr_skills;
  console.log(array[0].skills); This worked ..it returns PHP which was expected to be returned.

Comment: Great...you can use for-loop if there are many objects inside arr_skills and also use ng-repeat directly in the view

Comment: Yes..Thank you..Appreciated!

Comment: i want to update the PHP to some other skill from downdrop... i am trying to do this: array[0].skills = $scope.skills; which is not working.

Comment: if you want to update the value for the skills of php then you should do this. a[0].arr_skills[0].skills = $scope.skills  . array[0].skills is different variable it won't update your original array

Comment: a[0].arr_skills[0].skills = $scope.skills;
console.log(a[0].arr_skills[0].skills); i tried this one it prints PHP 3 times..though m updating it to HTML as skills.

Comment: for(var i = 0;i< array.length;i++){
               a[0].arr_skills[0].skills = $scope.skills;
                console.log(a[0].arr_skills[0].skills);
            }

Comment: for(var i = 0;i< array.length;i++){
               a[0].arr_skills[0].skills = $scope.skills;
                console.log(a[0].arr_skills[0].skills);
                console.log($scope.skills);
            } also i tried printing both values it gives PHP 6 times.. that means $scope.skills is also havin PHP value.. it is not binding to my dropdown i guess..

Comment: can you post your drop down code? and since you are using console inside loop it will print as many objects you have

Comment: you are using same array to show in dropdown and again trying to change  array value choosing dropdown?? can you elaborate

Comment: <select class="form-control" ng-model="skills">
                                <option value="">-- Select Skills --</option>
                                <option value="PHP"> PHP </option>
                                <option value="Angular JS"> Angular JS </option> 
                                <option value="Jquery"> Jquery </option>  
                                <option value="HTML"> HTML </option> 
                                <option value="CSS"> CSS </option>  
                                <option value="Ajax"> Ajax </option>  
                            </select>

Comment: i am jus trying to update my skill value in my array...which is actualy a nested array..

Comment: ok I got it..I think you should use ng-change in your select to check if the value is changing or not and also assign the json array change inside ng-change function in controller...<select class="form-control" ng-model="skills"  ng-change="change()"> <option value="">-- Select Skills --</option> <option value="PHP"> PHP </option> </select>    and in JS make function $scope.change() and  do your task there

Comment: i gues the value is not changing from dropdown ...But why is that happening?

Comment: it is anyways returning me the value i entered iniitailly not allowing me to update :(

Comment: ok I made a codepen...inspect it to see in console the changes..I don't know ur exact code but you can get something from here..http://codepen.io/nabinkumarn/pen/jqbVaX

Comment: 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' i am getting this error

Comment: are you getting error in your code or my codepen? there is no error in the codepen as i see. you can edit the code as your code and check or fork it and post your codepen and i can have a look

Comment: i am getting error in my code.. though i used the same from your code pen.. i am posting my code please have a look

Comment: $scope.updateSkill = function () {
        var a =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('candidateArray'));
        if (!$scope.skills) {
            alert("Enter Atleast One Skill");
        }else if (!$scope.level) {
            alert("Please Enter Expertise Level");
        }else {
            $scope.a[0].arr_skills[0].skills =$scope.skills;
            console.log($scope.a[0].arr_skills[0].skills);
            console.log($scope.a);
        } 
     }
     candidateArray is name i am storing my localstorage.

Comment: can you fork the codepen and edit with your code in codepen and give me the link..it would be easy